# Converting serial program to parallel using threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, full-text-search

I am writing a text search program for the Bible and I want to use threads to divide up the work so that the execution time cuts down. I'm moderately familiar with programming in Java, but completely new to the whole "threads" thing.  Basically, the program is pulling the separate books of the Bible, reading the text, searching for the word, and then pulling in the next book.  I want to divide this up so that 4-8 threads are working concurrently on separate books.

Any assistance?

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String wordToSearch = "";
    String[] booksOfBible;
    int bookPosition = 0;
    ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

    getWord gW = new getWord();
    getBook gB = new getBook();
    checkBook cB = new checkBook();
    wordToSearch = gW.getWord(wordToSearch);
    booksOfBible = gB.getFileList();
    //System.out.println(wordToSearch);
    for(int i = 0; i < booksOfBible.length; i++){
        //System.out.println(booksOfBible[i]);//Test to see if books are in order
        String[] verses = gB.getNextBook(booksOfBible, bookPosition);
        //System.out.println(verses[0]);//Test to see if the books are being read properly
        cB.checkForWord(wordToSearch, verses, booksOfBible[i], finalList);
        bookPosition++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < finalList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(finalList.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Word found " + finalList.size() + " times");
}
```

Comment: Faster searches would be possible by making a 'dictionary' of the texts.  Throwing extra threads at the matter is unlikely to help.

Comment: *"Any assistance?"*  Any (specific) question?

Comment: It's a good idea to read a few tutorials before diving into multithreading, see for example [this one](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5e_multithreading.html). Parallel programming is very difficult, and experience with single-threaded programming doesn't really prepare you for it.

Comment: I'm with Andrew on this one. Some problems are better solved with better data structures rather than extra resources.  I think this is one of them; build an index to avoid doing brute force search.   *If*, after building a high performance index, you *still* need it go faster, then maybe going parallel will help.  (I doubt it will help much; people have demonstrated extremely fast searches on things much bigger than the Bible).  [Side note: A brute force search of a Bible-size text buffer using tightly coded machine code is likely to search at gigabytes per second; that's not fast enough?]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implements `Runnable` and implement your text searching inside the `run()` method.

This is then runnable in a new thread by creating a new Thread object with the Runnable object as the constructor argument

```
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnableObj);
t.start();
```

Presumably you'll also need a data structure for multiple worker thread to store the result. Make sure you use thread-safe / synchronized data structure

However as Andrew Thompson pointed out, it might be faster for you to index the whole bible (eg: [using MySql fulltext searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or other libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nbNeededThreads) would give you an ExecutorService instance and this would let you submit parrallel tasks. Once getting the list of "Future", you can monitor those and know when their all done.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
ArrayList<Future> queue = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < booksOfBible.length; i++){
    Futur futurTask = service.submit(searchingTask);
    queue.add(futurTask);
}

// TODO Monitor queue to wait until all finished.
```